# Juniper MX204 licensing model

Tags: juniper

We have in mind to purchase a Juniper MX204 with base license, i want to know can we have ebgp and ibgp and using full table on this router?
Some people says that ebgp is not supported with base license.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as licensing for modern MX204 purchases, the licensing doc you need to reference is [this one](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/license/flex/flex-license-for-mx-series-routers-and-mpc-service-cards.pdf).

| License Model | Feature Buckets | Use Case Examples or Solutions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Standard | Bridging with port and single level VLAN (dot1Q), and LAG | Basic Layer 2 |
| Advanced | 1. IP routing, IGP (OSFP and IS-IS), IP-FRR, PIM variants, and IGMP, 2. Internet eBGP peering, BGP multihoming (add path and multi-path), EPE, and BGP PIC, 3. BGP Flow specification, 4. ... [see doc] | Transport |

So, yes, you need the `Advanced` license for the use of any routing on the MX204. Do note, this is an honor based license, and not technically enforced on the device.

Comment: Would you explain about honor-based licenses? it means that we can use ebgp and ibgp without a license but if we want should purchase it to have technical support on them?

Comment: Honor based means that it will technically work on the router, but will nag you with syslog messages or configuration warnings. It will not enforce scale or prevent you from configuring it. And yes, you do need to purchase it to have support on those protocols.